# NYT summary extractor python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, api

I am trying to access the summary of the NYT articles using the NewsWire API and python 2.7. Here is the code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2
from json import loads
import codecs
import time
import newspaper

posts = list()
articles = list()
i=30
keys= dict()
count=0
offset=0
while(offset<40000):
    if(len(posts)>=30000): break
    if(700<offset<800):
        offset=offset + 100
    #for p in xrange(100):    
    try:
        url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/nyt/all.json?offset="+str(offset)+"&api-key=ACCESSKEY"    
        data= loads(urlopen(url).read())
        print str(len(posts) )+ "  offset=" + str(offset) 
        if posts and articles and keys:
            outfile= open("articles_next.tsv", "w")
            for s in articles:
                outfile.write(s.encode("utf-8") + "\n")
            outfile.close()

            outfile= open("summary_next.tsv", "w")
            for s in posts:
                outfile.write(s.encode("utf-8") + "\n")
            outfile.close()    

            indexfile=open("ind2_next.tsv", "w")
            for x in keys.keys():
                indexfile.write('\n' + str(x) + "    " + str(keys[x]))
            indexfile.close()

        for item in data["results"]:
            if(('url' in item) & ('abstract' in item)) :

                url= item["url"]
                abst=item["abstract"]
                if(url not in keys.values()):
                    keys[count]=url
                    article = newspaper.Article(url)
                    article.download()
                    article.parse()
                    try:
                        el_post = article.text.replace('\n\n',' ').replace("Advertisement Continue reading the main story",'')
                    except XMLSyntaxError, e:
                        continue                    
                    articles.append(el_post)
                    count=count + 1
                    res= abst # url + "    " + abst 
                    # print res.encode("utf-8")               
                    posts.append(res) # Here is the appending statement.

            if(len(posts)>=30000): 
                break

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e
        time.sleep(1)
        offset=offset + 21
        continue
    except urllib2.URLError,e:
        print e
        time.sleep(1)
        offset=offset + 21
        continue

    offset=offset + 19
print str(len(posts))
print str(len(keys))
```

I was getting is good summary. But sometimes I came across some weird sentences as a part of the summary. Here are the example:

```
Here’s what you need to know to start your day.
Corrections appearing in print on Monday, August 28, 2017.
```

which are consider to be a summary of some article. Kindly, help me in extracting the perfect summary of the article from the NYT news. I thought of using the titles if such the arises, but the title is weird too.

Comment: I assume the summary text will be in their own <div> element right? How about removing the texts within those tags?

Comment: Actally I am trying to get the summary from the API snippet. The summary, I didn't found on the website anywhere or even in the div of the site. Hence, had a lot of problem. Can you help with it?

Comment: Can you explain how the article is structured when you receive it? Is it pure text? Do these weird sentences always appear at the end of each article AND a new line? Then, it would be easier to replace the last few lines of each article.

Comment: As you see the NewsWire API of NYT is completely in json format. As you see in the program I have handled it with JSON library and have tried to extract it. But sometimes the summary is not what I am expecting as per article. As you can see the weird sentences in the question. Hence, I am looking to solve this query that how I can extract the summary from the article which a bit of match for the text and I can get rid of the inappropriate sentences, what I am receiving.

Comment: See this : https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/cd5b3b194938c259dc637a9fc5b8885e

Comment: Does `el_post` contain the summary you extract for each article? Which also includes the unwanted statements, if I am not wrong.

Comment: No.. no. `el_post` contain the article. The `res` contains the abstract or summary I need.

Comment: Can you post the `res` variable for one article, on git? We don't have control over what is extracted, maybe we can try doing something after the text is extracted, at the `string` level in Python.

Comment: Here is the link for articles extracted: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/e8057f17b99f69719393c79a6cd84b18 and here is the link for the summary extracted using the script:  https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/503fd451d8841ab9657656e31c28eefd

Answer (score 0):

So, I have a taken a look through the summary results.

It is possible to remove repeated statements such as `Corrections appearing in print on Monday, August 28, 2017.`, where only the date is different.

Simplest way to do this is to check if the statement is present in the vairable itself.
Example,

```
# declare at the top
# create a list that consists of repetitive statements. I found 'quotation of the day' being repeated as well
REMOVE_STATEMENTS = ["Corrections appearing in print on", "Quotation of the Day for"]
```

And then,

```
if (statement not in res for statement in REMOVE_STATEMENTS):
      posts.append(res)
```

As for the remaining unwanted statements, there is NO way they can be differentiated, unless you search for keywords within `res` that you want to ignore, or they are repetitive. If you find any, just simply add them to the list I created.

Comment: Well, what you have said is right but the problem is we need to make changes in both the summary file and the article file which I do not want to do. That's why I was searching for some answer that will save my extra text processing efforts and directly can get me the answer.